# firing EVENTS only to a specific dynamic object?

Tags: c#, events

Here's my code so far. I have the main form and wcf objects that are created dynamically when a client connects. Right now all wcf objects subscribe to events being fired from the main form.

Yet I want the user to be able to pick a name from the main form's comboBox and fire an event only to the wcf object, that submitted this name.

What do you think would be the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

```
namespace server2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event EventHandler sendEvnt;
        private ServiceHost duplex;

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     /// once the form loads, create and open a new ServiceEndpoint.
        {
            duplex = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServerClass));
            duplex.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IfaceClient2Server), new NetTcpBinding(), "net.tcp://localhost:9080/service");
            duplex.Open();
            this.Text = "SERVER *on-line*";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sendEvnt(this, new EventArgs());
            // this send an event to all WCF objects
            // what should I do for it to send an event ONLY to the wcf object, that's name is selected from the comboBox ?
        }
    }


    class ServerClass : IfaceClient2Server
    {

        IfaceServer2Client callback;

        public ServerClass()
        {
            callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IfaceServer2Client>();
        }

        public void StartConnection(string name)
        {
            var myForm = Application.OpenForms["Form2"] as Form2;

            myForm.comboBox1.Items.Add(name);
            myForm.comboBox1.SelectedItem = name; // adds a name to form's comboBox.

            myForm.sendEvnt += new EventHandler(eventFromServer); // somehow need to incorporate the 'name' here.

            callback.Message_Server2Client("Welcome, " + name );
        }

        void eventFromServer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = Application.OpenForms["Form2"] as Form2;
            string msg = myForm.tb_send.Text;
            if (msg == "") { msg = "empty message"; }
            callback.Message_Server2Client(msg);
        }

        public void Message_Cleint2Server(string msg)
        {
        }

        public void Message2Client(string msg)
        {
        }

    }




    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "server", CallbackContract = typeof(IfaceServer2Client), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]


    public interface IfaceClient2Server           ///// what comes from the client to the server.
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void StartConnection(string clientName);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Message_Cleint2Server(string msg);
    }


    public interface IfaceServer2Client          ///// what goes from the sertver, to the client.
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void AcceptConnection();

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void RejectConnection();

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Message_Server2Client(string msg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are the WCF objects stored?  I assume you are storing them in some sort of collection.  If that is the case, try changing your collection to a `Dictionary<string, WcfObjectType>`.  From there you can lookup the object in the Dictionary based on the string the user has entered.